# Count number of workers at end of each month with entry-date and retired-date

Tags: r, dataframe

I have dataframe with company-entry-date and retire-date. From this dataframe I wanna count number of workers at the end of each month.

-Dataframe has company-entry-date and retire-date.

```
ID entry-date retire-date
===========================
1  2008-05-06 2010-03-03
2  2008-06-04 2009-02-25

I wanna count like this
Time        NumberOfWorkers
===============================
2008-05-31  1
2008-06-30  2
2008-07-31  2
......
2009-02-28  1
.......
2010-03-31  0
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

`lubridate` package has functions to easily extract parts of date objects; For instance

```
library(lubridate)
month("2011/11/07")  # 11
year("2011/10/07")   # 2011
```

**Edit:** JoeArtisan pointed out that the `zoo` package can be used to create a year-month variable (see his comment), which would be an interesting alternative. The code could easily be adapted to work with such a viariable. (end Edit)

So you could calculate new columns, one that would contain years, and one other containing months. You end up with a new dataframe (keeping only those new columns with made-up dates)

```
entry.year entry.month retire.year retire.month
2008       12           2010        06
2007       05           2009        05
2009       04           2011        11
2010       03           2012        01
```

Let's use even more fake data and see where it leads us...

```
dat <- read.csv(text=
"entry.year,entry.month,retire.year,retire.month
2008,12,2010,06
2007,05,2009,05
2009,04,2011,11
2010,03,2012,01
2008,12,2011,01
2007,05,2010,06
2009,03,2011,01
2010,03,2012,01
2008,11,2009,07
2007,05,2011,11
2008,04,2010,02
2010,03,2011,06
2008,09,2012,01
2007,05,2010,06
2009,03,2011,01
2010,03,2012,01")
```

Then you could use the following to get frequencies:

```
entries <- as.data.frame(table(dat[,1:2]))
retires <- as.data.frame(table(dat[,3:4]))
colnames(entries) = c("Year", "Month", "Freq.entries")
colnames(retires) = c("Year", "Month", "Freq.retires")
```

And merge those tables

```
final <- merge(entries, retires, by = c("Year", "Month"), all=TRUE)

# Replace NA values with 0
final[is.na(final)] <- 0

# Calculate the monthly fluctuation in employees
final$difference <- final$Freq.entries - final$Freq.retires

# And a cumulative sum
final$cumul <- cumsum(final$difference)
```

**Results**

```
> final
   Year Month Freq.entries Freq.retires difference cumul
1  2007     3            0            0          0     0
2  2007     4            0            0          0     0
3  2007     5            4            0          4     4
4  2007     9            0            0          0     4
5  2007    11            0            0          0     4
6  2007    12            0            0          0     4
7  2008     3            0            0          0     4
8  2008     4            1            0          1     5
9  2008     5            0            0          0     5
10 2008     9            1            0          1     6
11 2008    11            1            0          1     7
12 2008    12            2            0          2     9
13 2009     3            2            0          2    11
14 2009     4            1            0          1    12
15 2009     5            0            1         -1    11
16 2009     9            0            0          0    11
17 2009    11            0            0          0    11
18 2009    12            0            0          0    11
19 2009     1            0            0          0    11
20 2009     2            0            0          0    11
21 2009     6            0            0          0    11
22 2009     7            0            1         -1    10
23 2010     3            4            0          4    14
24 2010     4            0            0          0    14
25 2010     5            0            0          0    14
26 2010     9            0            0          0    14
27 2010    11            0            0          0    14
28 2010    12            0            0          0    14
29 2010     1            0            0          0    14
30 2010     2            0            1         -1    13
31 2010     6            0            3         -3    10
32 2010     7            0            0          0    10
33 2011     5            0            0          0    10
34 2011    11            0            2         -2     8
35 2011     1            0            3         -3     5
36 2011     2            0            0          0     5
37 2011     6            0            1         -1     4
38 2011     7            0            0          0     4
39 2012     5            0            0          0     4
40 2012    11            0            0          0     4
41 2012     1            0            4         -4     0
42 2012     2            0            0          0     0
43 2012     6            0            0          0     0
44 2012     7            0            0          0     0
```

Then you could also, if relevant, go further and calculate aggregate stats for chucks of time (4 or 6 months, or whole years) pretty easily. For instance,

```
by(data = final$Freq.entries, INDICES = final$Year, FUN = sum, na.rm=TRUE) 
by(data = final$Freq.retires, INDICES = final$Year, FUN = sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

And so on and so forth... Lots of fun, no?

Comment: Nice answer @DominicComtois, but I was thinking you could use the `yearmon` function in the `zoo` package, which converts a date to a year-month format, rather than have separate month and year columns, e.g. `library(zoo); as.yearmon(as.Date("2011/11/07")) #"Nov 2011"`

Comment: Good idea! Care if I integrate it to my answer?

Comment: No problem. There's also a function called `seq.Date(from, to, by = 'month')` which you could use to find missing months in your `final` data frame.

Comment: Ok... feel free to edit, I'm off for today. Otherwise will edit it tomorrow. Thx for those suggestions! :)

Comment: Seems the post is now on hold... Will see if OP wants to refine their question, or maybe accept the answer as it is before going into more editing.